# What is the subject in the given sentence?

Tags: sentence, subjects, dummy-it

> It's not easy to do the right thing.

What is the subject in the given sentence? I don't think it's obvious in this sentence. I was taught that subject is something, that performs the verb. But I don't anything in this sentence that performs the verb.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _It_ is the dummy subject of your sentence. More information here: https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414

Comment: The subject is “it”. This is called an extraposed construction; one where the subject of the 'basic' version is extraposed to the end of the sentence, outside the verb phrase, and replaced by the meaningless dummy pronoun "it". The basic non-extraposed version would be "[To do the right thing] is not easy", where the subject is the bracketed infinitival clause.

Comment: When I was in school, and maybe still today, this was called an "expletive" construction, and the dummy subject is not the grammatical subject of the sentence.  The subject is the noun-phrase "To do the right thing." To err is human, and it is human to err. "It" is almost never used with a plural.  The other common expletive is "there,"  as in "There *is* one book on the table, and there *are* 200 pages in it."https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/there-is.html

Comment: @remarkl We know that "it" is the subject for two reasons: (1) it inverts with the verb to form an interrogative: "Is it not easy to do the right thing?", and (2) it occurs as the subject of an interrogative tag: "It's not easy to do the right thing, is it? Only pronouns are admissible in such tags, and a pronoun subject of the 'anchor' becomes the subject of the tag.

Comment: You cannot "perform"  *is not easy* as you can, say, *chop* or *run*.

Comment: @BillJ Is to do the right thing easy? In the second test, you are conflating "it" the expletive with "it" the pronoun.  In the interrogative tag, "it" represents the subject of the sentence, as in "Fred is the king, isn't he?" We wouldn't say "isn't Fred?", but that would be grammatically correct, as would "To do the right thing is not easy, is to do the right thing?"

Comment: @remark I'm not conflating anything. Dummy "it" is a pronoun, whatever you choose to call it. The fact that the tag in "It's not easy to do the right thing, is it"? is "is it" demonstrates that "it" is the subject of the sentence. Of course we would say "isn't Fred?", we'd say "isn't he"? I've already said that only pronouns can be the subject of a tag.

Comment: @BillJ We'll just have to disagree on this.  I cited one self-styled expert, and that's going to have to do for me.  The word "it" can be an expletive at the beginning of a sentence and a pronoun in an interrogative tag.  They are basically homonyms.  That's my story, and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: The terms 'expletive' and 'dummy pronoun' are synonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It* is the subject. It's known as a [dummy subject](https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414), which means that it fulfills the syntactic requirement for a subject without supplying any explicit meaning. This usage appears fairly common when describing events like the weather:

> It is raining.
>
> It's cold outside.

In your case, the sentence with *it* is an example of *[extraposition](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626)*, meaning that it stands in for another subject that appears elsewhere in the sentence. An alternative version would put the [infinitive clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/infinitive-clause-grammar-1691062) at the start of the sentence:

> *To do the right thing* **is** not easy.

*It* provides an alternative arrangement that brings the main verb closer to the start of the sentence, especially if the infinitive clause or other subordinate clause is longer:

> *It* **is** not easy *to do the right thing*.

Comment: I used Shoe's link on a dummy subject and fleshed out the research.

Answer (score 1):

> *It's not easy to do the right thing.*

The subject is the dummy pronoun "it".

This is called an extraposed construction; one where the subject of the 'basic' version is extraposed to the end of the sentence, outside the verb phrase, and replaced by the semantically empty "it".

The basic non-extraposed version would be

[*To do the right thing*] *is not easy*, where the subject is the bracketed infinitival clause.

Evidence that "it" is the subject is provided by these facts:

(1) it inverts with the verb to form an interrogative: *Is it not easy to do the right thing?.*

(2) it occurs as the subject of an interrogative tag: *It's not easy to do the right* *thing, is it*? Only pronouns are admissible in such tags, and the subject of the 'anchor' normally becomes the subject of the tag.